# How to change an image in parent web page from embedded bot response - architectural approach

Tags: c#, azure, iframe, botframework

Can anyone help with how to achieve the following objective ?

The scenario is that the customers web site will have an embedded bot (driven by QnA - which has already trialled well as a prototype). The bot is yielding answers to FAQ type questions, many of which (approx 50%), relate to images which help the user understand the answer. These images are often large diagrams. [If you imagine the bot is shown on the RHS of the web page, occupying , say, 20% of the screen real-estate. If the answer has an associated diagram,then ideally this would be automatically shown in the 80% of the real estate on the left.  A typical question and answer might be -
(Q) "How do I change the DIP switches on the PF800 ?"
(A) "You access the switches via the hatch on the bottom of the device (see diagram)" ... and the diagram would appear on the left.]

Ideally I need a way to display these diagrams automatically, if the associated bot response has an associated diagram. I'm assuming the bot will be embedded in an I-frame on the web-site, and I also have the ability to influence the web site design itself.

What is the best way to achieve this. I guess its about

1. "Knowing" which diagram is associated with any given answer ?
2. Having a way of automatically using that diagram name as a parameter, made available by the bot, and passed out of the iframe back "up" into the parent web page?

Any thoughts would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a business requirement to use an iframe for Web Chat, I would strongly suggest you use [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-webchat) to customize the chat experience. Really, that is its purpose.

In particular, look at the [04.api/c.incoming-activity-event](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/main/samples/04.api/c.incoming-activity-event) sample. It demonstrates how you can dispatch an event in the hosting page based on an incoming activity. For example, if there is a diagram available to be displayed, a named event activity (or message with a particular value appended) is sent by the bot. When Web Chat receives an activity with that named event (or other value), an event is dispatched in the page which a listener will then pick up and render the received (or otherwise stored) image.

I do something similar in a test bot I have. When I ask to see a map my coordinate location is sent with the request (with permission). My bot makes an API call to Azure Maps. As the API call response is returned (a generated URL), it is included in the returned activity (a postBack, in my case) back to Web Chat. Web Chat is configured to look for this kind of activity - I believe it is matching on the activity's 'name' property. When it sees this activity arrive, it dispatches a separate event in the page that, again, includes the generated URL. The page has an associated listener set up waiting for this event. As it is triggered, it appends HTML into the page that displays my location on a map via the included URL.

In short, this *should* be fairly easy to achieve.

Hope of help!